# SQLite database Firefox

Tags: firefox, sqlite, html

I want to create a SQLite database in Firefox (I can update my Firefox). According to my knowledge, Firefox does not give you SQLite database access. 
Is there a plugin or simple patch which gives SQLite database simulation in Firefox?

Answer (score 5):

No, Firefox doesn't support SQLite databases (on web pages). And it's not part of the HTML5 specification any more. [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) is the standardized database.

Mozilla is working on it, Chrome as well.

Comment: Microsoft has also stated that they will do IndexedDB and not SQLite

Comment: +1 @Paul Rouget. Very cool - thanks for the link. Had not read the latest revisions, but looks like they are making progress.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite Manager - a plug-in for Firefox - allows you to interact with SQLite databases. You can [download it here](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/5817).

Comment: Whether I can pro grammatically access this from my web page

Comment: not that I am aware of. Check out [Paul Rouget's response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703377/sqlite-database-firefox/2704007#2704007) about Indexed DB - that sounds more like what you want.